# SwipeRefreshLayout in Home Screen Widget

Tags: android, widget, swiperefreshlayout

Is it possible to implement SwipeRefreshLayout (pull to refresh) inside a home screen widget ?

I have a ListView in as a home screen widget, it works fine but when I surround it with a SwipeRefreshLayout it gives an error, no logcat though.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- ListView to be shown on widget -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/r2_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Any ideas / tips on how to do it will be really appreciated !

Comment: Only certain `View`s are allowed in an App Widget. That's why you're crashing. (And you should definitely be getting a stack trace somewhere.) https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: post your code and logcat here

Comment: @MikeM Right. I've read that page a few days ago, but couldn't remember these limitations. So in other words, there's no way to implement "swipe down to refresh" inside app widgets ?

Comment: Not as far as I know.